# Does this proof work?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

let $ a,b \in \mathbb{Q^c} $ and define $b> a$ prove that there exists a rational number x where $ b>x>a$

I have seen this proof done in a few ways some in textbooks others on this site form similar questions but what i want to know is if this proof by contradiction proves this is true for any a,b.

First since a,b can be any irrational number as long as they aren't the same im going to arbitrarily define $b\geq2$  and $a \leq 2 $ then start a proof by contradiction changing the argument into, Prove that there does not exist a rational number x between any $ a,b \in \mathbb{Q^c}$ since $ a < 2 < b $  We have that $2$ is not a rational number; clearly we have a contradiction but does this prove it for any a,b that are irrational or only when one is smaller and one is bigger than 2?

Comment: No, it is not enough. Suppose $a < b < 2$. What you've shown is the following: "If $a < 2 < b$, then there exists $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a < q < b$." This is trivial. That is, you're assuming the existence of what you're trying to show.

Comment: You need to be able to prove it for all $a,b$, so your assumptions about $a,b$ is only going to prove it for those pairs. How do you know it is true when $a=\sqrt{2}$ and $b=\sqrt{3}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(b-a)>0$. By the Archimedean property of the reals, there is some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n(b-a)>1$.  Hence $nb-na>1$, so there is an integer $m$ with $nb\ge m\ge na$; since $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}^c$ in fact $nb>m>na$.  We now divide by $n$ to get $$b>\frac{m}{n}>a$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the decimal expansion of a number. Use the elementary process of rounding to construct numbers. As an example, consider $2^{1/2}$ and $3^{1/2}$. You can determine that 1.42 is larger than $2^{1/2}$ and 1.7 is smaller than $3^{1/2}$ by computing directly the squares. Then use the Archimedean property.

Can you see how to generalize?

Comment: I know how to prove it using the Archimedean property. i just wanted to see if i could prove it using contradiction =(

Comment: Well to use a contradiction, try supposing that there were two irrational numbers which were "adjacent" in the sense that there were no rationals in the middle. As irrational numbers, they are infinite strings of digits which vary in at least one point. Using that last fact, can you see where to find the contradiction?